# Check if student is in right class and only show students that goes in the class that is pressed

Tags: javascript, json, click, addeventlistener

I have an assignnment where there is laid out a html script that shows radio buttons, saying the name of each class, and a json file that lists all the students names and which class they go too.

I wondered is there a way to use addEventListener to do this? Because that's what I have heard is the right solution, and I have to do what the professor says.

I am not allowed to change the HTML code.

```
fetch("studenter.json")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
  .then(function appendData(data) {
  var unordered = document.querySelector(".studenter");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].fornavn + ' ' + data[i].etternavn;
    unordered.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Studenter i IIKG1002 og IDG1011</title>
  <script defer src="js/studenterIKlasse.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/studenterIKlasse.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Studenter i IIKG1002 og IDG1011</h1>
  <p>Velg klasse</p>
  <div class="klasseVelger">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BIGEOMAT" />
      <label for="BIGEOMAT">Bachelor in Engineering, Geomatics</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BWU" />
      <label for="BWU">Bachelor in Web Development</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="ÅRWEB" />
      <label for="ÅRWEB">Web Design - One-year programme</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BIXD" />
      <label for="BIXD">Interaction Design - Bachelor's Programme</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="all" />
      <label for="all">Show all</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <ul class="studenter"></ul>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's an example of the json I want to display:

```
  {
    "fornavn": "Marcus Gimse",
    "etternavn": "Blikstad",
    "studieprogram": "Bachelor in Engineering, Geomatics",
    "forkortelse": "BIGEOMAT"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure

You were almost there

NOTE: I renamed data to students

```js
// fetch here and keep the data - uncomment the next 4 lines when ready
// let students = [];
// fetch("studenter.json")
//  .then(response => response.json())
//  .then(data => students = data);


// example data. Remove when doing fetch
const students = [{ "fornavn": "Marcus Gimse", "etternavn": "Blikstad", "studieprogram": "Bachelor in Engineering, Geomatics", "forkortelse": "BIGEOMAT"}];


// using delegation - i.e. a click on anything in klasseVelger will give the target in event.target
document.querySelector(".klasseVelger").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type && tgt.type === "radio") {
    const id = tgt.id;
    console.log(id); // can be removed
    var unordered = document.querySelector(".studenter");
    unordered.innerHTML = ""; // reset
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
      if (id === "all" || id === students[i].forkortelse) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + students[i].fornavn + ' ' + students[i].etternavn;
        unordered.appendChild(li);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Studenter i IIKG1002 og IDG1011</h1>
<p>Velg klasse</p>
<div class="klasseVelger">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BIGEOMAT" />
    <label for="BIGEOMAT">Bachelor in Engineering, Geomatics</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BWU" />
    <label for="BWU">Bachelor in Web Development</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="ÅRWEB" />
    <label for="ÅRWEB">Web Design - One-year programme</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BIXD" />
    <label for="BIXD">Interaction Design - Bachelor's Programme</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="all" />
    <label for="all">Show all</label>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <ul class="studenter"></ul>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried Your solution but I can't seem to do it right. I get the error data is not defined.

Comment: I am not sure what reload answer means, but I edited the code above.

Comment: In what line? The fetch or later? If later, then there is a place you did not rename data to students  - if in the fetch then something went wrong getting the data

Comment: Later on the if statement. Maybe I can send you what I have done and you can look at it.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you did. But maybe I need to put some of the original code in?

Comment: I didn't find a Message option but I asked a question on plungjan.name

Comment: It worked after all. I had not changed the right script. Sorry for wasting Your time. Thanks!